# Extracting HTML from a stateless React component that's been passed into a trigger event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, events, components

I'm trying to create a reusable modal that is rendered high in the DOM (direct child of `<body>`), and gets content passed to it from wherever.

I have to set the state of the modal with something like a trigger event (unless I'm overlooking another option). Redux is not an option, as I don't have it in the app.

My problem is that when I pass the component containing the content into the trigger event, it renders just the object, but none of the html. It makes sense to me why it works like this, but I can't seem to find a way to extract the content from that object.

My modal:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Rodal from 'rodal'

class ApplicationModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    modalIsOpen: false,
    htmlContent: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $(window).on('modalToggle', (e, content) => {
      this.modalToggle(() => this.setModalContent(content))
    })
  }

  setModalContent = (content) => {
    this.setState({htmlContent: content})
  }

  modalToggle = (callback) => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen}, callback())
  }

  modalClose = () => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false})
  }

  modalOpen = () => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true})
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Rodal visible={this.state.modalIsOpen} onClose={this.modalClose} closeOnEsc={true} className={this.props.rodalClasses}>
          <div id="modal-container">
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.htmlContent}}></div>
          </div>
        </Rodal>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ApplicationModal
```

My page:

```
    import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

class MyPage extends React.Component {

  render () {
    // This works
    const html = `
    <div className="modal-content">
      <p>This is a question.</p>
      <p>This is an answer.</p>
    </div>
    `

    // This does not work
    const ModalContent = () => (
      <div className="modal-content">
        <p>This is a question.</p>
        <p>This is an answer.</p>
      </div>
    )

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>My page</h1>

        {/* This works */}
        <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick={() => $(window).trigger('modalToggle', html)}>Learn more</a>

        {/* This does not work */}
        <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick={() => $(window).trigger('modalToggle', <ModalContent/>)}>Learn more</a>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MyPage
```

I'd like to be able to pass full components into the trigger event, so the content can be rendered with buttons and dynamic inputs.

Am I going about this completely wrong?

In case it's not obvious, Rodal is just a pretty modal library.

Comment: "Am I going about this completely wrong?"  Yes, you are.  jQuery isn't part of React.  As a general strategy, try just setting the content block and let the clicking be responsible for just opening and closing it.

Comment: How would you recommend setting the content block of a detached, reusable modal component? I'm trying to build this as something I can just open and close from anywhere, and pass in the content from whichever component is using it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing can be accomplished with Reactstrap (A bootstrap library specific for React) and the built in component Modal:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

const ApplicationModal = props => {
  const modalBody = (
    <div className="modal-content">
    <p>This is a question.</p>
    <p>This is an answer.</p>
    </div>
   );

return (
    <div>
    <Button color="danger" onClick={props.toggle}>
        {props.props.buttonLabel}
    </Button>
    <Modal
        isOpen={props.modal}
        toggle={props.toggle}
        className={props.className}
    >
        <ModalHeader toggle={props.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>{modalBody}</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={props.toggle}>
            Do Something
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={props.toggle}>
            Cancel
        </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
    </div>
);
};

export default ApplicationModal;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to stay away from large authoritative libraries like bootstrap. Rodal is super lightweight, easy to modify, and I like the enter/leave animations much more than the bootstrap modals I've worked with in the past. That being said, though, using Reactstrap still wouldn't solve my problem. I'd still have to set the content of the modal somewhere. I'm trying to set it externally, and only define the modal once in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` was messing it up. I guess it was trying to render straight HTML, rather than rendering the component I passed in as an executable function. Which... Makes sense now that I think about it...